# Add UIButtons to array on ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, option-type

I'm working through an example project.

I'm trying to count the number of UIButtons the ViewControllers view has, and then add them to an array, so that I can programatically access them i.e. change colour / title etc.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var cardButtons: [UIButton]!

    let cardForegroundColour = UIColor.white
    let cardBackgroundColour = UIColor.orange

    lazy var game = ConcentrationGame(numberOfPairsOfCards: (self.cardButtons.count + 1) / 2)

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        for case let button as UIButton in self.view.subviews
        {
            button.backgroundColor = cardForegroundColour
            self.cardButtons.append(button)
        }

        print ("number of buttons /(self.cardButtons.count)")
    }
```

So, it builds fine, but crashes on the append line with:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Now, if I set a breakpoint, the `button` object is a valid object.

I can change all the colours fine, but I just can't add them to the array of `cardButtons`.

I know I can setup `cardButtons` as a Collection Outlet, and wire them up manually, but I want to be able to change the UI and the code just adapts, so adding more buttons, or removing some, doesn't change the code or require manual rewiring.

I realise the problem is with my understanding of optionals, but I thought that the `!` at the beginning and the concrete object `button` was the right approach.

Comment: `cardButtons = view.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIButton }`

Comment: `var cardButtons: [UIButton]!` declares an optional that is initially `nil`.  Since you never assign an array to it, it crashes when you try to access it (since it is implicitly unwrapped).  Just create an empty array like Johannes shows in his answer and don't use the optional at all.

Comment: Also consider making a `UIButton` subclass, e.g. `CardButton` which would have the correct background already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that `cardButtons` is `nil`.

Change this line `var cardButtons: [UIButton]!` to `var cardButtons = [UIButton]()`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Do not forget to check mark my answer ;)

Comment: Just had to wait for it to allow to me mark it as the answer. Thanks again!